# Selenium php unit. error undefined varible

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

Can anyone help me out.

```
class myClass_DataProviderAddInventory extends MinkTestCase {
  private $_addlotid = array(
    array( 'camera','Nikon'),
    array( 'Dslr','canon')  
  );

   public function SetValueForUpdateParcel() {
    return $this->_addlotid;
    }

/**
 * @dataProvider SetValueForUpdateParcel
 */
    public function testaddinvenotry($newValue,$oldvalue) {
    $this->waitForPageToLoad(1000);
    $this->assertElementSetWithValue_W('css',#item_title','#cid', $newvalue,$oldvalue);

    Selenium_Helper::clickInventorySubmitButton($this);
    Selenium_Helper::clickOkButton($this);
    Selenium_Helper::isProductLinkExists($this);
    Selenium_Helper::isAddLinkExists($this);

    $this->getSession()->wait(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the original error message?